# Find previous element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just start learning  programming and first time here.

I tried a Todo List

```
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <div id="cont">
        <input type="text" id="task_todo" placeholder="Add a task">
        <button type="button" id="add" onclick="add_task()">Add task</button>
    </div>
    <p id="att">No task add</p>
    <div id="todo_list"></div>
    <button id="clear_all">Clear all tasks</button>


function add_task(){
    var x=$("#task_todo").val();
    if (x==""){
        $("#att").fadeIn(1000).show(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    } else {

        $("#clear_all").show();
        
        var dv=document.createElement("div");
            dv.setAttribute("class","task");   
        var inp=document.createElement("input");
            inp.setAttribute("type","text");
            inp.setAttribute("class","in in_red");
            inp.value=x;
        var img_check=document.createElement("img");
            img_check.setAttribute("class", "check");
            img_check.setAttribute("src","images/check.png")
        var img_delete=document.createElement("img");
            img_delete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
            img_delete.setAttribute("src","images/delete.png");
        dv.appendChild(inp);
        dv.appendChild(img_check);
        dv.appendChild(img_delete);
        document.getElementById("todo_list").appendChild(dv);
        
        $(".check").click(function(){
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("in_green");
        })

        $(".delete").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
            if($(`#todo_list`).is(`:empty`)) 
                $("#clear_all").hide();
        })

        $("#clear_all").click(function(){
            $(".task").remove();
            $("#clear_all").hide();
        })

        $("#task_todo").val("");
    }   
}
```

My problem:

- add a task, button "check" work, change "input" field color
- add a second task, button "check" work for task 2, not for task 1
- add a third task, button "check" work for task 3 and 1, not for task 2

Maybe you can help me, thank you!

For Franci: for every task added, the "check" button changes the color of input field (content of task), from red to green, if task is done> Sorry if i wasn't very clear and thank you for interest.

Comment: Could you provide more infomation, like what you want to acheive, what problems you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning the click handlers to *all* the matching elements:

```
$(".check").click(...
```

so after first append, this adds a click event to the first button - but after second append it adds it to both first and second buttons.  So clicking on first button runs it twice (as it was already there for the first append) - and as it's a `.toggle()`, it effectively undoes what it did so appears to do nothing.

Same for third append - the first button now has three event handlers so appears to now work while the second has two event handlers so appears not to work.

You have 2 options: add a context to your event handler:

```
$(".check", dv).click(...
```

or, use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".check", function() {
```

you're already using `this` and that will continue to work for event delegation.

Note that with event delegation, you set the event handler up *once* (outside any other events) so will be in a different place from your append code.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your answer, but work perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to add any additional explanation if it will help.  This might help: liberally add `console.log($(".check").length)` (and other `console.log($("[whatever]").length)`) lines throughout your code so that you can get an idea of what's being selected.